# Unable to make SignalR, Web API, and SystemJS work together

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, systemjs

I am trying to build a notification service on my Web API that notifies the JavaScript (Aurelia) clients (WebApp). My Web API, and WebApp are in different domains.

I have a simple `NotificationHub`:

```
public class NotificationHub:Hub
{
    public void NotifyChange(string[] values)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastChange(values);
    }
}
```

I am configuring SignalR in `Startup` of Web API as follows:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:9000", "*", "*");
    httpConfig.EnableCors(cors);

    app.MapSignalR();

    WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);
    ...
}
```

In my WebApp, I am trying to access the `signalr/hubs` from my Web API as follows:

```
Promise.all([...
        System.import('jquery'),
        System.import('signalr'), ...
            ])
       .then((imports) => {
            return System.import("https://localhost:44304/signalr/hubs");
            });
```

I have also added a `meta` section in my `config.js`:

```
System.config({
    ...
    meta: {
        "https://*/signalr/hubs": { //here I also tried with full url
            "format": "global",
            "defaultExtension": false,
            "defaultJSExtension": false,
            "deps": ["signalr"]
        }
    }
});
```

Despite of these configurations, I still have following problems:

1. The request for `signalr/hubs`, from WebApp, is made as `https://localhost:44304/signalr/hubs.js`, and a `HTTP 404` is returned. Note that browsing `https://localhost:44304/signalr/hubs` returns the `hubs` script.
2. On `$.connection("https://localhost:44304/signalr").start()`, I am receiving following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44304/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&_=1471505254387. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Please let me know what I am missing here?

**Update:**
Using the appropriate CORS configuration, and the [gist](https://gist.github.com/donald-slagle/bf0673b3c188f3a2559c) suggested by @kabaehr I am now able to connect to SignalR hubs. However, the broadcast (push notification) is still not working.

My SignalR configuration:

```
public static class SignalRConfig
{
    public static void Register(IAppBuilder app, EnableCorsAttribute cors)
    {

        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            var corsOption = new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context =>
                    {
                        var policy = new CorsPolicy { AllowAnyHeader = true, AllowAnyMethod = true, SupportsCredentials = true };

                        // Only allow CORS requests from the trusted domains.
                        cors.Origins.ForEach(o => policy.Origins.Add(o));

                        return Task.FromResult(policy);
                    }
                }
            };
            map.UseCors(corsOption).RunSignalR();
        });
    }
}
```

I am using it in `Startup` as follows:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:9000", "*", "*");
httpConfig.EnableCors(cors);

SignalRConfig.Register(app, cors);

WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);
```

And I am trying to push notifications as follows:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>().Clients.All.broadcastChange(new[] { value });
```

However, my clients are not notified on `broadcastChange`. I am assuming that I don't have to import `https://localhost:44304/signalr/hubs` explicitly, when I am using the  [gist](https://gist.github.com/donald-slagle/bf0673b3c188f3a2559c).

Comment: Your origin is not using `https` it seems? Just try `"*"` at first to get around the issue.

Comment: @MarkC. Thank you for your comment. I have tried with `"*"`, however, I can't really say whether it is working or not, as `SystemJS` appends `.js` at the end of `signalr/hubs`, and I am getting a `404`. I think that needs to be handled before somehow, but I am not sure how.

Comment: there are several plugins for system js with which you can prevent the append of ".js" like https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text but i don´t know if this is the problem.

Comment: Take a look at this. it works for me https://gist.github.com/donald-slagle/bf0673b3c188f3a2559c

Comment: @kabaehr Thank you for your comment. It helped somewhat. I have updated the question. You may take a look if you want.

Comment: @kabaehr I think finally I made it work. I think the problem was that I was calling the `hubConnection.start()` method before registering any callback. And that was what creating the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great :) would you like to post your solution as answer? So others facing this problem can easily see the answer

Comment: @kabaehr I would like to do that. My knowledge on SignalR is bit fragmented right now. Will share the complete answer in coming days.

Comment: @kabaehr Little bit late :) but as told, I have posted the answer. You may take a look if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to share my findings and what solved the problem for me.

So to start with, `signalr/hubs` is just a auto generated proxy from the server side code. It is not necessary to use that proxy if you can create your own SignalR proxy client. Below is one such simple SignalR client that is created based on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/donald-slagle/bf0673b3c188f3a2559c) mentioned by @kabaehr. The SignalR client is quite simplistic in nature as of now.

```
export class SignalRClient {

    public connection = undefined;
    private running: boolean = false;

    public getOrCreateHub(hubName: string) {
        hubName = hubName.toLowerCase();
        if (!this.connection) {
            this.connection = jQuery.hubConnection("https://myhost:myport");
        }

        if (!this.connection.proxies[hubName]) {
            this.connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
        }

        return this.connection.proxies[hubName];
    }

    public registerCallback(hubName: string, methodName: string, callback: (...msg: any[]) => void,
        startIfNotStarted: boolean = true) {

        var hubProxy = this.getOrCreateHub(hubName);
        hubProxy.on(methodName, callback);

        //Note: Unlike C# clients, for JavaScript clients, at least one callback 
        //      needs to be registered, prior to start the connection.
        if (!this.running && startIfNotStarted)
            this.start();
    }

    start() {
        const self = this;
        if (!self.running) {
            self.connection.start()
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('Now connected, connection Id=' + self.connection.id);
                    self.running = true;
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log('Could not connect');
                });
        }
    }
}
```

*One important thing to note here is that for a JavaScript SignalR client, we need to register at least one callback method before starting the connection.*

With such client proxy in place you can use it as below. Though the code sample below uses `aurelia-framework` in general, but the SignalR part in `attached()` has nothing to do with Aurelia.

```
import {autoinject, bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
import {SignalRClient} from "./SignalRClient";

@autoinject
export class SomeClass{

    //Instantiate SignalRClient.
    constructor(private signalRClient: SignalRClient) {
    }

    attached() {
        //To register callback you can use lambda expression...
        this.signalRClient.registerCallback("notificationHub", "somethingChanged", (data) => {
            console.log("Notified in VM via signalr.", data);
        });

        //... or function name.
        this.signalRClient.registerCallback("notificationHub", "somethingChanged", this.somethingChanged);
    }

    somethingChanged(data) {
        console.log("Notified in VM, somethingChanged, via signalr.", data);
    }
}
```

This is the crux of the solution. For the parts associated with enabling CORS is already mentioned in the question. For more detailed information, you may refer to these links:

- [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)